# ClassFormatError after Proguard Optimization (no obfuscation) of Guice enabled application

Tags: java, exception, guice, proguard

I have a Guice enabled application working fine, but when I optimize it (i.e., shrink size) with Proguard, I get the following error message (I catch it with an uncaught exception handler):

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: LVTT entry for 'that' in class file
com/google/inject/internal/util/$ImmutableList$RegularImmutableList
does not match any LVT entry
```

This prevents the application from operating properly. I do not obfuscate the code.

Does anyone know what is happening? Is there a solution/workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes ProGuard will rip out more things than it should when shrinking.  ProGuard will remove any references to classes/members that it believes are not used in your application unless you explicitly tell it to preserve those classes/members.

You can preserve classes/members using [ProGuard's keep options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/usage.html#keepoptions).  The [example usage page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html) has a few examples of keep options.

I see this happen sometimes when my applications reference an interface implementation which doesn't appear to be referenced when you're just looking at the code.  I just add a new keep option every time I find that something is missing.  Perhaps someone else has a better suggestion for how to track these things down?

Comment: I tried different options to remove problematic classes, but I kept getting issues. I have finally removed Guice from my code and shrinking now works super fine. The app works again.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you are using the latest version of ProGuard, version 4.6 at this time of writing.

Based on other reports, there may however still be a bug (#3161222) in the optimization step, not always processing the optional LocalVariableTable and LocalVariableTypeTable attributes correctly. Therefore, three simple work-arounds:

- compile without these attributes (javac -g:lines,source), or
- let the obfuscation step remove the attributes (don't specify -dontobfuscate, don't specifiy -keepattributes LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable), or
- don't optimize (-dontoptimize).

The attributes are intended for debugging, and generally not very useful or even desirable in obfuscated code.

Comment: I did use version 4.6. If you want, I could create a small maven project replicating the issue and put it on pastebin. Just let me know.

Comment: @JVerstry Thanks for the offer. I think can work from the earlier reports for now.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod 
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
```